# I want to read text from a file containing a paragraph, split words and then assign to an array

Tags: c, arrays, string, readfile

The text file contains:
"Opening from A Tale of Two Cities by Charles Darwin

It was the best of times, it was the worst of times. It was the age
of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness. It was the epoch of
belief, it was the epoch of incredulity."

I am not sure where am I getting wrong.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define max_words 20
#define max_story_words 1000
#define max_word_length 80

int main()
{
    char story[max_story_words][max_word_length],ch;
    int num_words=1;
    FILE *file_story=fopen("TwoCitiesStory.txt", "r");
    if (file_story==NULL)
        printf("Unable to open %s\n","TwoCitiesStory.txt");
    else{
        ch=fgetc(file_story);
        while(ch!=EOF){
            if(ch==' '||ch=='\n')
                num_words++;
                ch=fgetc(file_story);
        }
        int i=0;
        //assigning each words to story[i]
        while (i<max_story_words && fgets(story[i], max_word_length, file_story) != NULL) {
            if( story[i][strlen(story[i])-1]=='\n'||story[i][strlen(story[i])-1]==' '||story[i][strlen(story[i])-1]==','||
               story[i][strlen(story[i])-1]=='!'||story[i][strlen(story[i])-1]=='.'||story[i][strlen(story[i])-1]==':'||
               story[i][strlen(story[i])-1]==';'||story[i][strlen(story[i])-1]=='?'||story[i][strlen(story[i])-1]=='-'||
               story[i][strlen(story[i])-1]=='?')
                //remove a newline here
                story[i][strlen(story[i])-1]='\0';
            i++;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<num_words;i++){
        printf("story[%d]: %s\n",i,story[i]);
        }
        printf("%d",num_words);
    }
        return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issues with your code are (1) You fail to rewind `file_story` after you read the stream to `EOF` counting words, and (2) you don't tokenize each line read by `fgets` into words before assigning to `story[i]`. What happens is `fgets` reads an entire line at a time (which is what you want). However, it is then up to you to break each line into words and remove the punctuation characters.

To do this you want either `strtok` or `strsep`. `strtok` is well suited for the job. A careful choice of the delimited list will allow you to break the lines up into words and assign the words to `story[i]` at the same time.

Also, for heavens sake, let your code breathe... Yes, you can cram everything together and remove all the spaces, which is close to obfuscation in my book. Spacing lines and expanding the syntax a bit makes your code **much** more readable. (you might even find it helps make it easier on you to code) But to each his own there. If you like it condensed, that's fine.

Look over the following and let me know if you have questions. I changed the code to take the filename as an argument so it is not hard-coded. You run the program and place the filename on the command line. Good luck:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define max_words 20
#define max_story_words 1000
#define max_word_length 80

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: insufficient input, usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char story[max_story_words][max_word_length] = {{0}};
    char line[max_story_words] = {0};
    char *p;
    char ch = 0;
    char *punct="\n ,!.:;?-";
    int num_words = 1;
    int i = 0;
    FILE *file_story = fopen (argv[1], "r");

    if (file_story==NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open '%s'\n",argv[1]);
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* count words */
    while ((ch = fgetc (file_story)) != EOF) {
        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n')
            num_words++;
    }

    /* you already read file_story to EOF, so you must rewind to
       reset the EOF condition and place the file pointer at the start */
    rewind (file_story);

    i = 0;
    /* read each line in file */
    while (fgets (line, max_word_length, file_story) != NULL) 
    {
        /* tokenize line into words removing punctuation chars in punct */
        for (p = strtok (line, punct); p != NULL; p = strtok (NULL, punct))
        {
            /* convert each char in p to lower-case with tolower */
            char *c = p;
            for (; *c; c++)
                *c = tolower (*c);

            /* manually convert each char in p to lower-case */
            // char *c = p;       /* save start address of p */
            // for (; *c; c++)
            //     if ('A' <= *c && *c <= 'Z')
            //         *c += 32;

            /* copy token (word) to story[i] */
            strncpy ((char *)story[i], p, strlen (p));
            i++;
        }
    }

    /* output array */
    for(i = 0; i < num_words; i++)
        printf ("story[%d]: %s\n", i, story[i]);

    printf("\ntotal words: %d\n\n",num_words);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**Above:** I chose to include the code using `tolower` to convert the characters to lowercase. If you are just learning C, then it is better to get familiar with all of the character handling functions before you start writing your own. (I have left the manual conversion included, but commented out so you can learn from it as well)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am just a beginner. What if I want to convert all letters of a word to lowercase before storing to the array?

I added this loop just before the output array, didn't work:

for(int i=0;i<num_words;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<strlen(story[i]);j++){
        if(story[j]>=65&&story[j]<=90)
        story[j]+=32;
    }
    }
@david

Comment: Add `#include <ctype.h>` as a header file, then change `strncpy ((char *)story[i], p, strlen (p));` to convert all characters to lower. I'll update the example. You've made the right choice to learn C. Nothing else provides the power and control that C does, but with that great power comes great responsibility. Learning C is a journey, not a race. Enjoy the journey.

Comment: Also, no need to add `#include <ctype.h>` when done manually. Look at the ASCII characters [**ASCII Code - The extended ASCII table**](http://www.ascii-code.com/). Notice that the value for all lower-case characters are simply `32` greater than the upper-case version. So you just check each letter in the string and if it is upper-case, `add 32` to it's value to change it to lowercase.  (there is also a `tolower(char p)` function in `ctype.h`. You can use either method. (`add 32` or call `tolower(ch)` for each character in your string).

Comment: **Note:** you have to save the original start address for `p` so that you can `p` still points to the beginning of the word when you call `strncpy`, so simply create another character pointer `char *c = p;` and use pointer `c` to step through each character of the word when you convert to lowercase.

Comment: Thanks a lot and again sorry to bother you. If you run this code with the text file I mentioned very beginning with a completely empty line at line 2 and an unnecessary white space after the final full stop of the text (after wrong.) you will get 48 words as output with 2 white spaces, while it was suppose to be 46. @david

Comment: Yes, I didn't know what you wanted to do with them. POSIX specifies that each line in a file will end with a `newline` (even if empty), so depending on how you want to handle that, you will either check the length and skip counting if length `<= 1` (the newline only or EOF). The question was put on hold, otherwise I'd provide an example. You should be able to add the check without much problem.